# Dynamic programming algorithm and recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Does anyone know how to answer this problem? I have been stuck for a few days trying to figure it out.

A students decides to ride her bicycle from Vancouver to Halifax.
She starts on the road at kilometer 0. Along the way there are n hotels H1, . . . , Hn, at
distances h_1 < h_2 < h_3 < . . . < h_n−1 < h_n from the trip’s starting point respectively.
The only places where the student is willing to stop for the night are these hotels, but she
can choose which hotels she stops at. She must stop at the final hotel H_n since this is her
destination (she is planning on flying back).
Ideally, this student would like to travel 100Km per day, but this may not be possible,
depending on the spacing of the hotels. In order to determine how close the student got
to this target distance, she defines the penalty for a day to be |100 − x|^1.5 where x is the
distance traveled that day. Her objective is to plan her trip in a way that minimizes the
sum of the daily penalties over all days of the trip.

- Write a recurrence relation for D_k, where D_k is the minimum sum of the daily penalties, over all possible trips that end at hotel H_k (that is, the student does not go any further)
- Find a dynamic programming algorithm that computes D_n.

Comment: any code to show that you have tried anything? It might be useful for us to help you out.This also looks like a bit of homework.. XD

Comment: The question mentioned no limitation on how far she can go in one day. It says "this student would like to travel 100Km per day" - does that mean this is the limit?

Comment: No, I don't think that's any hard limit. I think she can go all the way to `H_n` during the first day. (It's just that the penalty will be huge.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to think about this problem is to think backward. Lets say you are at Hotel N, what was the last optimal last? Was it n-1? n-2? n-3?. Then, you pick the best and work backward until to get to the starting point

```
 F(n) = min( F(j) + abs(100 - h_n + h_j)^1.5 ) where 0 < j < n
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, this sounds like a greedy approach. Picking an optimal last leg might force you to pick a suboptimal second-to-last leg.

Comment: @aioobe, it has dynamic programming properties. It has overlapping subproblems and optimal substructure.

Comment: The problem yes, but I don't see how your solution uses dynamic programming. Picking the optimal last leg (without thinking about the consequences for the remaining ones) and then move on to the next-to-last leg seems greedy to me.

Comment: @aioobe, Because to compute F(n), you will have to compute F(1), F(2), F(3), ... many times. So, you can use "memoization". Your approach and my approach are basically the same. You just work from bottom up and I work from top down.

Comment: If `h_n` is at `1000`, and `h_(n-1)` is at `900` (i.e. it's 100 km between the last two hotels), then your algorithm will *definitely* pick `h_(n-1)` as the last stop before going to the destination. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @aioobe, that's not necessary true. It could be, but if there is other last stop that perform better than, it will pick other stop.

Comment: Hmm, so how could a stop be more optimal than 100 km away? That's penalty 0. (It seems to me that your solution *will* pick `h_(n-1)` in this case, no?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79922/discussion-between-invisal-and-aioobe).